# mod_python equivalent to php exec() command

Tags: php, python, exec, mod-python

what is the mod_python equivalent to the php exec command?

```
$cmd = '/var/www/scripts/test.py' + $parameter
$return = exec($cmd)
```

I've tried this but it doesn't return anything

```
varReturn= subprocess.check_output(['/var/www/scripts/resolveID.py ', varParameters)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the stdout and stderr of the subprocess:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(['/var/www/scripts/resolveId.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```